# application.properties of Spring Boot project in VSCODE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-boot-test

Currently I'm using VScode for spring boot project.

I have a problem with application.properties of my spring boot project.

There are two 'application.properties' files in my project.

- file_1. src/main/resources/application.properties
- file_2. src/test/resources/application.properties

In file_1, there is "spring.profiles.active=local" + some other properties for setting,
In file_2, there is "spring.profiles.active=test" + some other properties for setting.

- test code is integrated with springframework for using spring container by @SpringBootTest annotation.

I expected that file_1 is used for main code, and file_2 for test code.
But, test code also use file_1 for setting.

For IntelliJ, there's no problem for above situation. Then, Why VScode cannot apply application.properties for each context(main, test)?

Is there any solution for this situation?

P.S Using @ActiveProfiles is not working for my situation. It only changes logs.

Comment: Hi&welcome! "But, test code also use file_1 for setting." (I.m.o.) correct, they are "combined/merged", where "test" has (higher) priority...

Comment: Please explain: "...VScode cannot apply" (run/build config/terminal?)

Comment: @xerx593 I mean when i run test codes(which use beans in spring container) in VScode, i expected that spring boot uses 'src/test/resource/application.properties' for settings(e.g. database connection setting, etc.). but it still uses 'src/main/resource/application.properties' for settings.

Comment: @xerx593 so, my question is why 'src/test/resource/application.properties' is not used for springboot configuration of test code in VScode instead of 'src/main/resource/application.properties'.

Comment: `src/test/resources` or "resource" ?(plural or singular?) plural is correct/important (in maven/gradle defaults)

Comment: @xerx593 'resources' is right. If you make springboot project with spring initializr, it's a default structure of project directory.